# How to use View.updateDragShadow()

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

My app does not behave correctly on drag & drop for Android 7.0+. I read from below that they introduced `View.updateDragShadow()` which replaces the drop shadow. Currently in Android 7.0+,my drop shadow when the view has been dropped will float away to its original drag location and the view will appear again at the dropped location.

How do I use `View.updateDragShadow()` to update the drop shadow to where I am currently dragging it?

Comment: I would like to know this too.